# How do I test my react component inside storybook properly?

Tags: reactjs, testing, storybook

I'm creating a react app and using storybook to visualize and test it.

I'm trying to make an interaction test for language switcher component by using play function and assertion.

Story for language switcher component:

```
export const Simple: Story = {
    args: {},
    play: async ({ canvasElement, step }) => {
        const canvas = within(canvasElement)

        const buttonName = canvas.getByRole('button', { name: 'ru' })

        await step('Expecting button UI', async () => {
            await expect(buttonName).toBeInTheDocument()
        })

        await step('Expecting button to have attribute and value', async () => {
            await expect(buttonName).toHaveAttribute('type', 'button')
        })

        await step('Expecting button to have a special class', async () => {
            await expect(buttonName).toHaveClass(
                'src-shared-ui-Button-Button-module__button src-shared-ui-Button-Button-module__lang'
            )
        })
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see then I change a language and get back to the story again, the test fails.

It's because of that line:

```
const buttonName = canvas.getByRole('button', { name: 'ru' })
```

I need to make `{ name: 'ru' }` dynamic. How I can do that?

I can do that like so:

```
const { i18n } = useTranslation()
const buttonName = canvas.getByRole('button', { name: i18n.language === 'ru' ? 'ru' : 'en' })
```

**Questions**:

1. How I can get useTranslation hook inside my story and so get i18n instance inside my play function if my real LanguageSwitcher component doesn't take any props.

Code for LanguageSwitcher component:

```
export const LangSwitcher: FC = () => {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()

    const toggleLang = async (): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            await i18n.changeLanguage(i18n.language === 'ru' ? 'en' : 'ru')
        } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof Error) {
                throw new Error(error.message)
            }
        }
    }

    const language = t('ru')

    return (
        <Button
            onClick={toggleLang}
            className={ButtonTheme.LANG}
        >
            {language}
        </Button>
    )
}
```

2. Do I use a good practise to test my switcher component like that. Is there any better practise?